# Attach bootstrap filestyle as append in bootstrap 2

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I'm trying to attach [Markusslima's Boostrap Filestyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) as append to a fake input in Bootstrap 2.3.2.

There must be some kind of a conflict and no matter what I try (adding placeholder, etc,etc) nothing seems to work.
I am just starting in javascript and have been stuck here since 2 weeks now.

Here is my attempt:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="input-prepend input-append span12"><span
 class="add-on"><i class="icon-picture icon-large"></i></span>
     <input type="text" class="span9" style="margin:0;" placeholder="Press the Browse button to upload your photo" /> 
          <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="img_upload_file" id="img_upload_file" accept="image/*" data-classButton="btn"
 data-input="false" />
          <input type="hidden" name="ajax-nonce" id="ajax-nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('upload_img'); ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="mode" id="mode" value="computer" />
       <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="fms-upload-img" />
 </div>
```